# How to remove lines in large text file which have less than 500 at the end

Tags: database

I have a large text file, approx 7000 lines. With format like this

xxxyyy534xxxyyy | Char: 000

I want to remove all lines where Char is below 500, but im worried because some of the starts also have numbers.

I have no idea about coding or how to do this in the slightest, I just know there must be a better way than manually deleting 7000 lines

Comment: What does 'starts also have numbers' mean? Is this just on a unix system? What is the range of values at the end of the line?

Comment: I mean there is numbers at the beginning part, but I only want to check the value of the Char: 000 . The numbers range from 0-3500 , mostly under 1000.  I want to remove all which have Char: 499 or lower, e.g Char: 324.    Also, I believe unix is what I have, im just using a mac with textedit file

Comment: Is there only one pipe character in each line, separating the beginning and end parts?

Comment: And is the number after `Char: ` always three digits?

Comment: Pipe character? You mean this? | yes, just one of these. In the exact format I stated. Not always 3 digits. Up to 4 digits, for example, some say 0, some, 16, some 1202

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` on a Mac, Linux or UNIX system you can remove the line with:

```
sed '/Char: [0-4][0-9][0-9]$/d' < inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

This matches all numbers 0-499 where that is the last character (fixed by `$`) on the line.

Comment: Sorry im bad with this, do I run this in terminal somehow?

Comment: Yes. Run the above in the directory of the file. Use `cd {path}` to get to the right directory. The output goes to `outputfile.txt` so if something isn't right you haven't lost your original.

Comment: Sorry im still stuck, how do i run it in the directory?

Comment: Think I may have almost got it working, I put it all in terminal and dragged in both files, input and output. It didnt save anything to the output and basically it just wrote out the whole input file in terminal without removing any of the low Char ones